# How to set jQuery Events only on Textarea?

Tags: html, jquery

I would like to know that How to set jQuery Events only on Textarea and not other elements. Please look at the following code:

```
<div id="divUnique">
    <textarea id="txtArea" name="txtArea" cols="100"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" size="20"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk"/>
</div>
```

I will have a common `DIV` called `divUnique` and, later, dynamically pairs of `TEXTAREA`, `FILE INPUT` and `CHECKBOX` will be added.

I want to set three events called `click`, `change` and `keypress` only on `TEXTAREA` and not other elements in `DIV`.

So, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#divUnique").on("click change keypress","#txt",function(){
    // your work goes here
});
```

reference **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: Do I need to separate events by , (comma) or space? And by doing this still file input and checkbox are not workable.

Comment: sorry with spaces it works and thanks for focus i update my code see changes @NullVoid and now it works on textarea

Comment: fuinction should be function

Comment: You're welcome :) I checked it but still `file input` and `checkbox` are not in workable condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //click
    $("#txt").click(function(){
        alert("textarea clicked");
    });
    //keypress
    $("#txt").keypress(function(){
        alert("key pressed");
    });
    //change
    $("#txt").change(function(){
        alert("changed");
    });
})
```

demo link:
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ronjon/jeWRr/)

Comment: I cannot know `id` of dynamically created `textarea`. So I cannot bind event in advance. I can only know `id="divUnique"` div. So any suggestion on this?